# How to minus the sum of one query to the sum of another query in the same oracle sql table?

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, difference

I have 2 queries, both are returning sum, **I want the difference between those sums in a single query.**

```
Query 1:
   select sum(Records) from my_table where column1 ='1' and column2 = 'abc'
Query 2:
    select sum(Records) from my_table where column1 ='2' and column2 = 'adf'
```

note both queries having same table_name.

```
My table:
column1 column2  column3     column4  records
1           aa   something      abc    12
2           bb   something      acd    25
2           aa   something      adf    04
1           bb   something      abc    21
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the your existing queries as the columns and take the difference.

```
with my_table (column1, column2, column3,column4,  records) as 
    ( select 1, 'aa', 'something', 'abc',  12   from dual union all       
      select 2, 'bb', 'something', 'acd',  25   from dual union all 
      select 2, 'aa', 'something', 'adf',  04   from dual union all 
      select 1, 'bb', 'something', 'abc',  21   from dual
    )   
select r1, r2, r1-r2 diff
  from  (select sum(Records) r1 from my_table where column1 ='1' and column4 = 'abc')
     ,  (select sum(Records) r2 from my_table where column1 ='2' and column4 = 'adf');
```

Note: I changed the queries to reference column4 instead of column2 in order to match the sample date provided.

Comment: Thanks, @Belayer, this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when column1 = '1' and column2 = 'abc' then Records
                when column1 = '2' and column2 = 'adf' then - Records
                else 0
           end) as diff
from my_table ;
```

Comment: Thanks @ Gordon , I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want to keep queries you've already written, use them as CTEs:

```
with 
a (suma) as 
  (select sum(Records) from my_table where column1 ='1' and column2 = 'abc'),
b (sumb) as
  (select sum(Records) from my_table where column1 ='2' and column2 = 'adf')
select a.suma - b.sumb as difference
from a cross join b
```

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot, I appreciate your efforts

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Oracle handy today but this should get you close.

```
select ( select sum(Records) from my_table where column1 ='1' and column2 = 'abc') -  
(select sum(Records) from my_table where column1 ='2' and column2 = 'adf') 
as Total from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks @Northbank, I appreciate your effort